# Hyperledger composer file permissions issue?

Tags: node.js, permissions, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to setup hyperledger composer locally. But when I install generator without sudo i get error of **EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\''**, On the other hand when I use sudo to install the npm package it changes the ownership to nobody and then nothing seems to work.

```
npm install -g generator-hyperledger-composer
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: hi, our docs https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html - we explicit state not to install Composer using root or sudo. This causes problems for Node package manager `npm` itself (and ultimately, therefore, Composer which uses npm). Just create a simple non-root user, uninstall any part installs using `npm uninstall -g xxxx` as your present user. Then login as your 'new user' and then follow https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html including the pre-reqs script - it couldn't be simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the npm install/config, and not a specific Hyperledger Composer problem.  It is covered here: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions